# Laravel 5 add back routes.php NotFoundHttpException

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-5

In the last update to to Laravel 5 they removed the routes.php file in favor of Annotations. I still wish to use the routes.php file though. I read that you simple create the file in app/Http/routes.php and uncomment

```
//require app_path('Http/routes.php');
```

Inside the RouteServiceProvider.php file. I tried and I still get the NotFoundHttpException. For the following route.

```
Route::get('/', 'PagesController@home');
```

Inside the PagesController

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;


class PagesController {

public function home()
{
    return 'test';
}

}
```

Can anyone tell me how to re enable it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After uncommenting `//require app_path('Http/routes.php');` you need to run:

```
php artisan clear-compiled
```

Otherwise your `RouteServiceProvider` is compiled and Laravel won't see the change you made in this file source

Comment: @hooligan Glad I could help, I also had to look what's the issue. I thought first that it's because or routes caching in Laravel 5 but it was because of compiling some files